# How to add authorization header when runtime import webpack chunks of Vue components

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

The purpose of this task is to make it impossible to download the Vue-component package (*.js file) knowing the address of the component, but not having an access token.

I'm developing an access control system and a user interface in which the set of available components depends on the user's access level.

The system uses the `JSON API and JWT authorization`. For this, Axios is used on the client side. To build the application, we use Webpack 4, to load the components, we use the `vue-loader`.

After the user is authorized, the application requests an array of available routes and metadata from the server, then a dynamically constructed menu and routes are added to the VueRouter object.

Below I gave a simplified code.

```
            import axios from 'axios'
            import router from 'router'

            let API = axios.create({
              baseURL: '/api/v1/',
              headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer mySecretToken12345'
              }
            })

            let buildRoutesRecursive = jsonRoutes => {
              let routes = []
              jsonRoutes.forEach(r => {
                let path = r.path.slice(1)
                let route = {
                  path: r.path,
                  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "restricted/[request]" */ 'views/restricted/' + path)
                  //example path: 'dashboard/users.vue', 'dashboard/reports.vue', etc...
                }
                if (r.children)
                  route.children = buildRoutesRecursive(r.children)
                routes.push(route)
              })
              return routes
            }

            API.get('user/routes').then(
              response => {

                /*
                  response.data = 
                        [{
                      "path": "/dashboard",
                      "icon": "fas fa-sliders-h",
                              "children": [{
                        "path": "/dashboard/users",
                        "icon": "fa fa-users",
                                }, {
                        "path": "/dashboard/reports",
                        "icon": "fa fa-indent"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                */

                let vueRoutes = buildRoutesRecursive(response.data)
                router.addRoutes(vueRoutes)   
              },
              error => console.log(error)
            )
```

The problem I'm having is because Webpack loads the components, by adding the 'script' element, and not through the AJAX request. Therefore, I do not know how to add an authorization header to this download. As a result, any user who does not have a token can download the code of the private component by simply inserting his address into the navigation bar of the browser.

[image: import dashboard-reports.vue]

Ideally, I would like to know how to import a vue component using Axios.

[image: import using ajax]

Or, how to add an authorization header to an HTTP request.

[image: Auth header in script request]

Comment: It is uncommon to protect the client side code behind a password. It's normally enough to just protect the data.

Answer (score 3):

I needed something similar and came up with the following solution.  First, we introduce a webpack plugin that gives us access to the script element before it's added to the DOM.  Then we can munge the element to use fetch() to get the script source, and you can craft the fetch as needed (e.g. add request headers).

In webpack.config.js:

```
/*
 * This plugin will call dynamicImportScriptHook() just before
 * the script element is added to the DOM. The script object is
 * passed to dynamicImportScriptHook(), and it should return
 * the script object or a replacement.
 */
class DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
      "DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin", (compilation) =>
        compilation.mainTemplate.hooks.jsonpScript.tap(
          "DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin", (source) => [
            source,
            "if (typeof dynamicImportScriptHook === 'function') {",
            "  script = dynamicImportScriptHook(script);",
            "}"
          ].join("\n")
        )
    );
  }
}

/* now add the plugin to the existing config: */
module.exports = {
   ...
   plugins: [
     new DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin()
   ]
}
```

Now, somewhere convenient in your application js:

```
/*
 * With the above plugin, this function will get called just
 * before the script element is added to the DOM. It is passed
 * the script element object and should return either the same
 * script element object or a replacement (which is what we do
 * here).
 */
window.dynamicImportScriptHook = (script) => {
  const {onerror, onload} = script;
  var emptyScript = document.createElement('script');
  /*
   * Here is the fetch(). You can control the fetch as needed,
   * add request headers, etc. We wrap webpack's original
   * onerror and onload handlers so that we can clean up the
   * object URL.
   *
   * Note that you'll probably want to handle errors from fetch()
   * in some way (invoke webpack's onerror or some such).
   */
  fetch(script.src)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      script.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      script.onerror = (event) => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(script.src);
        onerror(event);
      };
      script.onload = (event) => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(script.src);
        onload(event);
      };
      emptyScript.remove();
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
  /* Here we return an empty script element back to webpack.
   * webpack will add this to document.head immediately.  We
   * can't let webpack add the real script object because the
   * fetch isn't done yet. We add it ourselves above after
   * the fetch is done.
   */
  return emptyScript;
};
```

Comment: I just want to follow up with this. We have an issue where we needed something like this. We tried this code you added and it didnt work. Is there any update to this? Did you make an actual webpack plugin that you use that uses fetch for getting js modules?

Comment: I did not distribute a plugin, mostly because I haven't taken the time to figure out how, but everything I needed I posted here, and this code did work for me (not exactly because my fetch was tailored to my app).  If it helps, I am using webpack 4.16.1.  In what way is it not working for you?  I also have a solution that uses a web service worker, but it seems finicky.

Comment: Oh, also, my js is split between some public modules that do not require this hook to load and some non-public modules that do need the hook.  The 'public' modules load first without the hook, then I use react-loadable to trigger the dynamic import of the non-public modules that need the hook.

Comment: Together with Neriesta's answer, this works great. The only issue I encountered was that the `{ onload }` property is always null for me. Not sure why, but I just added another check to it.

Answer (score 3):

Although [sspiff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9206834/sspiff)'s answer looks quite promising, it did not work directly for me.

After some investigation this was mainly due to me using Vue CLI 3 and thus a newer version of webpack. (which is kinda weird as [sspiff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9206834/sspiff) mentioned using webpack 4.16.1).

Anyway to solve it I used the following source: [medium.com](https://medium.com/coursera-engineering/webpack-3-to-4-facing-the-known-unknowns-and-unknown-unknowns-cdfeb817faf8), 
Which gave me the knowledge to edit the given code.

This new code is situated in vue.config.js file:

```
/*
 * This plugin will call dynamicImportScriptHook() just before
 * the script element is added to the DOM. The script object is
 * passed to dynamicImportScriptHook(), and it should return
 * the script object or a replacement.
 */
class DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
      "DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin", (compilation) =>
        compilation.mainTemplate.hooks.render.tap(
          {
            name: "DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin",
            stage: Infinity
          },
          rawSource => {
          const sourceString = rawSource.source()

          if (!sourceString.includes('jsonpScriptSrc')) {
            return sourceString;
          } else {
            const sourceArray = sourceString.split('script.src = jsonpScriptSrc(chunkId);')

            const newArray = [
              sourceArray[0],
              'script.src = jsonpScriptSrc(chunkId);',
              "\n\nif (typeof dynamicImportScriptHook === 'function') {\n",
              "  script = dynamicImportScriptHook(script);\n",
              "}\n",
              sourceArray[1]
            ]

            return newArray.join("")
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
}

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new DynamicImportScriptHookPlugin()
    ]
  }
}
```

The second piece of code provided by [sspiff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9206834/sspiff) has stayed the same and can be placed in the App.vue file or the index.html between script tags.

Also to further improve this answer I will now explain how to split the chunks in Vue CLI 3 for this specific purpose.

as you can see I also added the chainWebpack field to the config. This makes sure that webpack does not add prefetch tags in the index.html. (e.g. it will now only load lazy chunks when they are needed)

To further improve your splitting I suggest changing all your imports to something like:

```
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "public/componentName" */ /* webpackPrefetch: true */'@/components/yourpubliccomponent')

component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "private/componentName" */ /* webpackPrefetch: false */'@/components/yourprivatecomponent')
```

This will make sure that all your private chunks end up in a private folder and that they will not get prefetched.
The public chunks will end up in a public folder and will get prefetched.

For more information use the following source [how-to-make-lazy-loading-actually-work-in-vue-cli-3](https://medium.com/@mrodal/how-to-make-lazy-loading-actually-work-in-vue-cli-3-7f3f88cfb102)

Hope this helps anyone with this problem!

Answer (score -1):

To perform a simple component download using an access token, you can do the following...

1) Use asynchronous component loading with file extraction. Use `webpackChunkName` option to separate file or directory/file, like:

```
components: {
    ProtectedComp: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "someFolder/someName" */ './components/protected/componentA.vue')
  }
```

2) Configure server redirection for protected files or direcory. Apache htaccess config for example:

```
RewriteRule ^js/protected/(.+)$ /js-provider.php?r=$1 [L]
```

3) write a server-side script that checks the token in the header or cookies and gives either the contents of .js or 403 error.

Comment: Sure, but this misses the step where you actually insert your access token, as the other answers outline