# Send headers with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, axios

I already searched for a good while on the Internet and even checked all suggested questions here, but I found nothing.

Basically, I'm using vue-router to load views when the user clicks on them (without prefetching, just lazy-loading), using a function that imports the Vue view/component. To better visualize, I made a barebone example of what I'm doing:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    ...
    {
      path: "/a_page",
      component: function() {
        return import("./views/A_Page.vue");
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

I'm using Express in the backend to protect certain routes, because protecting it in the Frontend is wasted effort, since the user could bypass the 'protection' easily, if he wants to. Also all views have their own splitted .js file (using ["webpackChunkName"](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)) and Express needs a Bearer Authentication Token header for every API call *OR* `.js` file requested. This works great with Axios (responsible for fetching API data) where you can manually define a header, but vue-router hasn't this option, and since it doesn't send the Authorization header, it doesn't authenticate, Express blocks the file with a 403 and vue-router fails to import the file.

Is there any way to send the Authorization header with the import (which is basically just a GET request)?

Thanks in advance.

---

*If someone thinks I'm approaching the problem in a wrong way, feel free to comment and suggest another way.*

---

EDIT: The suggested duplicate question was given too little attention and the only solution given (which is basically split in 2) doesn't work with the current webpack anymore; onload(event) and onerror(event) get undefined.

Comment: Does your Express view embed the data you want protected, or is it just a component that then requests data from the API? If you really want to protect your client-side code, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/49731460/2486583

Comment: @JamesIrwin I'm not sure if I understood you right. Express handles both the API and the files. All API calls are made to "/api/...." and all files are loaded requesting to "/....". The API call returns JSON and the files are mainly .js ones, which hold Vue views which then request the API through Axios and are then populated with actual data.

Comment: The Idea I thinks, is why do you want to protect component if they contains no data. The Js files can be accessible by everybody. When these Js are loaded, they will call the api, then you recieve an error 401 or 403 if you are not authenticated or if you dont have the good right

Comment: @Sodala But the Vue view even if it contains no *actual* data, the entire structure is loaded and a attacker (or someone a little too curious) could trick the route into loading and then analyse the entire page: What do we have, how do we sort things, what do we take into consideration, etc. This is not something I really want to show.

Comment: The file request is made by Webpack, not Vue Router. You can configure Webpack with a plugin to modify the headers when necessary. See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57927612/6277151)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add authorization header when runtime import webpack chunks of Vue components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731460/how-to-add-authorization-header-when-runtime-import-webpack-chunks-of-vue-compon)

Comment: @tony19 I appreciate your effort by marking this question as duplicate, but please consider that there are exactly two questions talking about this: The 'duplicate' one and mine. The 'duplicate' one despite talking about the same thing, didn't get a lot of attention and the only solution given is broken on newer webpack setups.

Comment: @Fusseldieb I voted this to be closed as a duplicate because it is essentially the same question as the original, but only worded differently (mainly because this question assumes the problem/solution is in Vue Router). Stack Overflow [discourages users from asking the same question only to give it more attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368273/should-i-ask-same-unanswered-question-again-after-finding-more-information-or-e).

Comment: @Fusseldieb The `onload` and `onerror` don't need to be defined. Adding a `null`-check at those calls would resolve the issue. I confirmed the posted solution works (so that headers could be added to requests of the dynamic imports).

Comment: @tony19 Yes, the routes load, despite onload/onerror reporting null/undefined, a null-check *could* solve, but... I haven't found out a way to send a response back to Vue-Router saying that the route failed to load (403, etc). It just loads and loads, until it reaches the default timeout of 30s, even if the load/import long failed. Is there a command to give a "error" response back to Vue-Router (that triggers 'router.onError')? That would solve the remaining issue.

Comment: Honestly, I think you are going on this issue in the wrong way. As @Sodala said, why protect some JS view that is just an dumb empty view?

You already have protected all of the API endpoints, by requiring Authorization header on each call.

If you still want to do some kind of extra Authentication, you could always use the beforeEnter on the specific route, see the docs here. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Comment: @dasmikko As I said earlier, how things are sorted and which dropdown options are available is already in my opinion too much information to just give to someone unauthenticated. I'm almost jumping to Vue SSR, it does (as I saw) just this. The entire page is assembled serveside-wise and I could write a Middleware to stop the page from loading. But this does not exactly solve the question, as I like the SPA aspect of Vue.

Comment: @Fusseldieb but then why show them the dropdown when they are not authenticated? If you want to go the SSR way, I can totally recommend Nuxt.js

Comment: I am not sure if it helps you but here a similar question was discussed:
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/issues/60

Comment: So maybe try adding crossorigin="use-credentials" to the script tags that are generated by webpack. Add it to the link tag for the chunk you want to include too. If it works you need to find a way to manipulate the Webpack output but that should be doable.

Comment: @dasmikko I'm looking into Nuxt. It seems like the way to go for this (without messing too much with webpack)

Comment: @David Do you have an idea on how to do this? At this point it's more for future viewers than me (see above comment on why)

Comment: First you should try if it really works. Where you would build you app and then change the index.html. I don't have a server with Auth right now to test.

Comment: I am no webpack expert but in you vue.config.js you normally have a pages property with the pages of your app. Inside each of those pages, all properties that are not Vue specific will be given to html-webpack-plugin.

Comment: You will probably need https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin to achieve the transformation. I know its not that straight forward

Answer (score 1):

You could use a router guard instead of protecting with basic auth.

I use this method, along with lazy loaded routes. If the auth fails you can redirect the user to a login page.

```
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    If (auth) { // get value of cookie etc for a jwt token or similar auth method
        next() // proceed
   }
   else {
        next(false) // cancel navigation
        // or
        next(“/login-url”) // redirect you login url
    }
})
```

Additionally, you could use an axios method to auth on each route change.

Comment: But this lies on the frontend, which can be bypassed. Even with lazy-load, the route itself isn't protected and can be tricked into loading.

Comment: You don't need to secure the frontend too much, just enough to ensure that users can't go to places they're not meant to go by accident. The real security should be on your backend to ensure that nobody without authorisation gets access to any data they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send up the Authorization header (which doesn't seem to be an easy task, given that no one knows how to go about it...) I think you could override webpack's jsonp function that it uses to load the chunks in splitChunks...

[Here's the docs for the webpack function that loads the chunks](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputjsonpfunction)

You'll override your webpack config with your modified chunk loading function and then tie that into your `vue.config.js` like so...

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: require('./webpack.config.js')
}
```

All this being said, I would suggest protecting your frontend assets much earlier than when you need to be loading your split chunks and not requiring the Authorization header to serve your static assets.

Sometimes you can do this at the network layer (load balancer, etc) depending on your use-case. Other times using a server-based approach, like rendering your app w/ Nuxt, will be what you want.

Comment: I've approached this problem in multiple different ways, but no matter how I look at it, neither is feasible (with Vue). The page itself contain fields or even i18n strings which contain potentially sensible information on how something should be made/sorted/etc. This isn't something I would like the www to see. The chance someone looking into it is low, but exists. A "solution" would be putting all strings inside the API, but then everything would become too fragmented and I would need to load every field and *literally* everything from the API, which isn't quite the plan (or fast/optimized).

Comment: For anyone looking into the same problem, I'm personally trying Nuxt for now, as it (should) render everything server-side and only deliver the fully assembled page. I'm making a "middleware" to check for Authentication - let's see how this goes.

Comment: Nuxt is a great tool for this stuff. Their `auth` option might be what you want.

Comment: I just tested the "auth" module, @Jess, and as I somehow expected, I can still see "protected content" without authentication. I loaded up the example page -> Devtools -> Network and there I can see the "protected" content.

Comment: I've found the "serverMiddleware" what seems like what I want... Too sad SO automatically awarded the wrong question. But thanks!

Comment: Awh, well I'm glad to hear that my answer helped you :-)

Yeah, serverMiddleware will let you put your webapp "behind" something.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly (feel free to correct me), would you be able to do an auth call with axios prior to the actual routing, or perhaps upon the routing using a mounted call?  Especially if there is no valid authentication you can then either redirect to a login page or re-route to an error page.

Feel free to let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You could use axios inside of a navigation guard, yes.

Comment: But webpack should send the Authentication header in the first place. And this can, as far as I know, only be done tapping into webpack and messing with its core functionality on how scripts are loaded/imported.

Comment: [Continuing above comment] which ideally also would need access to the Vuex store to retrieve the Bearer token string...